# How do I make my taskbar icons/items this small?

Tags: taskbar, icons

No matter what I try, it just won't work. I even tried changing the taskbar icons' size from the registry editor, but it won't make them this small.

[image]

Comment: Sure. I am on Windows 10. I tried all the methods I found on Google, and they were too many. I cannot list them all obviously. However, you can still see what I really need in the image above. Simply put, a taskbar with small icons like these.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1683326/edit) your question to answer such things, anyway please check out my post.

Answer (score 3):

- Go to
  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
- Create a new DWORD (32bit) `TaskbarSmallIcons` and set the value to
  1.
- Restart explorer after that. (End process `explorer.exe`, then File >
  New > `explorer`)

*This setting seems to have changed in Win11. (Will update this answer when Win11 Taskbar stops being a dumpster fire)

**Win11 - Edit:**

For Win11, the name of the DWORD should be '**TaskbarSi**'.

Values:

- 0 - Smaller
- 1 - Medium (default)
- 2 - Bigger

Win11 Taskbar is still missing some very important features.

Comment: Cool...Works for me!!!!

Comment: @Glitch, any chance you've figured it out yet for Win11? `TaskbarSmallIcons` still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Robert, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Glitch, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. Maybe it depends on the build number. I'm on Win11 22621.1702

Comment: @Robert yes, a march update seems to have broken that. I usually defer updates so I didn't notice it till later.

Comment: YES!  What life-saver!  Was driving me insane with giant taskbar on tiny laptop.  Mostly I use it for remoting in to other stuff or controlling my media rig on the wall panel.  But I switch back and forth a lot for testing and taskbar was always getting in the way, taking up precious screen-real-estate.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

There are various methods to make taskbar icons smaller in Windows 10, some of them are:

## 1. Using settings

- Right Click on the empty space on taskbar and select *Taskbar Settings* which has a gear icon before it.
- Now toggle the option *"Use small taskbar icons"*.

**The icons should be small immediately. If it is not changed, try signing out and signing back in, restarting.**
If this method didn't worked for you, check next method

## 2. Using Registry Editor

You already mentioned that Registry method didn't worked for you, but still I have included it.

**WARNING: You MUST backup your registry before you use this and any such methods! [Learn How.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692#:%7E:text=Back%20up%20the%20registry%20manually,-From%20the%20Start&text=In%20Registry%20Editor%2C%20locate%20and,Click%20Save.)**

- Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe)
- Go to following key:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
- Right click anywhere on empty place in editor and select DWORD (32-bit) value.
- Change its value to *1*.

**NOTE: To make this method work, you MUST sign out and sign back in.**
If this method didn't worked for you, check next method.

## 3. Using Registry Editor (Another method)

**NOTE: This may not work on some machines.**

- Open regedit
- Go to reg:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
- Create a new DWORD value.
- Change the name to *TaskbarSI*
- Double Click on it and change the base to *Hexadecimal*.
- Change its value to 0 as its:

```
Small Size - 0
Medium Size (Default) - 1 
Larger Size - 2
```

**NOTE: Log out and Log back in to apply changes.**
If this method is also not working try the next method.

## 4. Unlocking  taskbar

- Right click taskbar and make sure *Lock the taskbar* is unchecked.
- Now move the mouse around the taskbar and stop when it looks like a arrow.
- Now drag the pointer down until taskbar becomes small.

**NOTE: This method might only make taskbar small, so move to next one.**

## 5. Changing Display settings.

**Important: This will make not only the taskbar, but EVERYTHING smaller.**

- Right click on empty space on desktop and select *Display Settings*.
- Now change the Percentage as:

[image]

**This may not work on all displays and all devices. This only works if you have separate display or high resolution graphics.**

## At last

These are the methods that worked in my computer. These are my researches and they might not work on all devices. Please reply which method worked for you. If none of those methods are working, or you have tried all of those, Notify me so that I can do more research and find out more tricks. If your device crashed or anything has stopped working after doing any registry tweaks, please restore the registry that you have backed up!

Comment: Your #2 solution does not say what to name the new DWORD value.  Since you say to set the value to `1`, I assume the name isn't `TaskbarSi`, because it's value must be 0 for small icons...